# Azure API Management integration in Azure Active Directory

Tags: oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, azure-api-management

I want to secure my API Proxy created in Azure API Management using OAuth 2.0.
I want to use Azure Active Directory for OAuth.
As per MS documentation, I have to manually create an Application in Azure AD and copy that CLIENT_ID and KEY into developer portal to generate OAuth Tokens. But this works only for developer portal to get JWT tokens.

Every time a new developer comes and registers a developer application on my developer portal, a pair of keys (Primary key & Secondary Key) are generated.
Can I use these keys to authenticate and generate JWT tokens. 
Also I want this process to be automated, so that I do not have to do anything manually in AAD after developer sign-up and subscription.

I have also tried to visually represent the scenario I want to achieve:

The pictorial representation of my requirement

[image: Please click to open the pictorial representation of my requirement]

Comment: Why do you want to use a token rather than skipping steps 3 and 4 altogether and just sending the primary key from the developer portal to Azure API management directly?

Comment: Also, it's important to note that in step 3, there isn't such a thing as Azure AD primary & secondary key. These are API Management keys, not Azure AD keys.

Comment: I do not want to send my developer keys with every request as there is potential security threat that in case keys get stolen by a hacker, I have to reset the keys.
While by using token, I am sending them one time to get Token. In case token gets stolen, I can invalidate it and generate a new token.

So far what I have not been able to figure out is that how to validate developer keys in Azure AD to generate token. All the links suggest to use keys generated by Azure AD while registering application in AAD for enerating access token.

Comment: Also For clarity I have updated text in my initial picture explaining the requirement